# UIKit v3 Tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, tabs, uikit

I started using UIKit (v3) and I'm really liking it. But I can't use uk-tab no matter how much I try. [In this pen](http://codepen.io/mateusfccp/pen/ryaXdZ) I have the code I'm trying to make, and you can easily see that (1) the uk-active class does nothing, (2) the content part of the tab is not showing and (3) clicking on any of the itens in the tab does nothing. I tried everything in [switcher](https://getuikit.com/docs/switcher#switcher-and-tab) and [tab](https://getuikit.com/docs/tab) documentation. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

```
<div uk-grid>
        <div class="uk-width-auto">
            <ul class="uk-tab-left" uk-tab="connect: #datas">
                <li><a class="uk-active" href="#">Domingo (20/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Segunda (21/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terça (22/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quarta (23/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quinta (24/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sexta (25/08)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sábado (26/08)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-expand">
            <ul id="datas" class="uk-switcher">
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Domingo -->
                        <li><strong>20h:</strong> Abertura com Concerto/Palestra na Igreja, sob a regência do Prof. Dr. Jetro, que apresentará e executará hinos compostos no contexto da Reforma</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Segunda -->
                        <li><strong>18h40:</strong> Credenciamento a partir das inscrições feitas anteriormente, via site</li>
                        <li><strong>19h30:</strong> Meditação e oração</li>
                        <li><strong>19h40:</strong> Conferência I: História e Teologia da Reforma</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Terça -->
                        <li><strong>16h45:</strong> Meditação e oração.</li>
                        <li><strong>16h55:</strong> Conferência II: Reforma e Educação</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Quarta -->
                        <li><strong>14h:</strong> Grupos de trabalho</li>
                        <li><strong>19h30:</strong> Meditação e oração</li>
                        <li><strong>19h40:</strong> Conferência III: Reforma e Eclesiologia</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Quinta -->
                        <li><strong>14h:</strong> Grupos de trabalho</li>
                        <li><strong>19h30:</strong> Meditação e oração</li>
                        <li><strong>19h40:</strong> Conferência IV: Reforma e Tradução</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Sexta -->
                        <li><strong>20h:</strong> Culto na igreja, com ênfase nos hinos do hinário acerca do tema do evento</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul class="uk-list"> <!-- Sábado -->
                        <li><strong>8h30 e 10h30:</strong> Encerramento do evento com sermão temático preparado pelo Pr. Dr. Jimmy</li>
                        <li><strong>16h45:</strong> Culto Jovem, com a projeção de excertos do filme Lutero, de Eric Till, 2003. Após o filme, mesa-redonda com a participação de professores dos cursos de História , Teologia e Rádio e TV. </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) the uk-active class does nothing

You have to add the class to the `<li>`, not to the `<a>`. It will then produce the following CSS, which affects the `<a>`:

```
.uk-tab > .uk-active > a {
    color: #333;
    border-color: #1e87f0;
}
```

---

> (2) the content part of the tab is not showing and (3) clicking on any of the itens in the tab does nothing

This one took me a while as I haven't used uikit before and the problems are caused by a bug in uikit. If you just change the `.uk-tab-left` to `.uk-tab` it will work, so I searched for related problems and found a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/2324). The author has *narrowed it down to the uk-tab-left class when [he tries] to put the tab list on the left side of the content*. This was 26 days ago. The [bug was fixed 5 days ago](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/commit/246320e28455721424a4aa910568594ab3176923), so it will be in the next version of uikit.

Here is an [updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZXKBr) that only applies the bugfix to the javascript.

Comment: You workaround didn't work for me. Anyway, a fix has been released already.